# How to make text bold or italic while posting a tweet to the Twitter account from my website

Tags: php, html, css, twitter

I am using Twitter OAuth library and PHP to post a tweet from my website to my Twitter account. I just want to make some text bold while posting. But couldn't able to find out how to do it. I have tried b tag but it doesn't work. Kindly help me to solve the issue. Below I have given sample code.

```
$CONSUMER_KEY = **********;
$CONSUMER_SECRET = **********;
$ACCESS_TOKEN = **********;
$ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = **********;

$postData = "Posting data from my website to twitter";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $ACCESS_TOKEN, $ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
$statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => $postData]);
```

Answer (score 8):

Answering half a year late because I googled this because I wanted to know, and it was top result with no answer.

Twitter doesn't let you format text in any way.

However, twitter does seem to support most if not all unicode characters, and there are bold unicode characters    which *are not formatted* texts, but separate characters entirely.

**These 2 sentences are made up of different characters.**

.

Check the raw text of this answer, the top sentence is *formatted* to be bold, whereas the bottom is using characters which ARE bold already. Which is why they look slightly different.

So to use this on twitter, you need to convert your string to use the unicode bold equivalents. A good online converter can be found here for both italic and bold types.

https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/

You can solve most uses with something like the below I wrote for my python program (sorry I don't use php, but the idea is the same).

```
def bold(input_text):

    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    bold_chars = ""

    output = ""

    for character in input_text:
        if character in chars:
            output += bold_chars[chars.index(character)]
        else:
            output += character 

    return output
```

The code above just has 2 strings, of the same letters and numbers in the same order. The function creates the output string by going through the input character by character and if it is found in the regular chars list, it adds on the character in the same position from the bold chars string. If it isn't found then it just uses the original char.

You can add more bold chars to the list if you need them. I've only used the main ones here.

The resulting tweets using this method will show up like this.

[image]

All this also works for italic unicode characters in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API doesn't seem to allow you to do that:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html

In any case I'd suggest you update your question and add the code you're using, someone may appear with a workaround.

Always providing a sample of your code makes everybody's life easier.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Should this not be a comment?

Comment: Actually, this is a straight forward answer with a reference to the source. 1st line "Twitter API doesn't seem to allow you to do that"

Comment: I've just read your answer and I must agree it's way better. 

Actually, I am up voting it as you've provided a nice workaround.